# unable resolve dependency android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

***i just wanna to know how to gradle plugin successfully build***

**ERROR**: **Unable to resolve dependency** for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

**

> build.gradle :project

**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> build.gradle :module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'


}
```

***i just wanna to know how to gradle plugin successfully build***

Comment: You are mixing androidX with support version. Just do the following will help you.
Menu bar `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX`. May be it'll show you warning for some duplicate dependencies. So just remove those duplicates and sync again.

Comment: when i create new project i am also have the same error with different gradle with sdk 29 and androidx implementation by default also having the same error when used the android support implementation

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

The Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries.

Details here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: two flags are already written in gradle.properties by default "true" and still have the error

Comment: follow **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** steps here

Comment: You can use `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'` rather than AppCompat suppot

Comment: i created new project to see where is the problem then when it get build i have the same error but i don't change the implementation of the **gradle.app** and that is dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}